# Bootstrap 3.0 navbar toggles

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Bootstrap 3.0. In this I have to use 2 navbar toggle I have applied one condition though it's working fine but it is a long procedure as I have to make another css for both navbar my code is below.

For navbar 1 I have take this code

```
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse"></div>
```

and for 2nd one I have used

```
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse2">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse2 collapse"></div>
```

Any one know the short method for this.

Comment: that's already the short method

Answer (score 0):

The div for each navbars should contain these 2 classes:
`collapse` and `navbar-collapse`

Then you can add your own class like `navbar-collapse2`

Comment: Thanks, i have used collapse also my both navbar are working but the problem is i have to make another css for navbar-collapse2 and its a long process cause navbar-collapse are too much. I was asking a short process in which i dont have to make many css classes.